# 2 PR for 2 commits on github

Tags: github

I am new to github. I wish to raise pr1 for my commit_file1 and pr2 for commit_file2. How to do that in github? I created different branches for the two commits but a PR always include both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to (assuming you don't have any work in progress):

- reset the first branch to commit1

  ```
   git switch branch1
   git reset --hard commit1
   git push --force -u origin branch1
  ```
- Then reset your second branch to before commit1, and cherry-pick commit 2

  ```
   git switch branch2
   git reset --hard commit1~
   git cherry-pick commit2
   git push --force -u origin branch2
  ```